# Checking if a hidden file exists with Serverspec

Tags: ruby, integration-testing, hidden-files, dotfiles, test-kitchen

I am using Test-Kitchen and Serverspec for my integration tests. I want to use a Serverspec file resource to verify whether a hidden file exists, in this case `.gemrc`. Here is my spec configuration:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Checking the .gemrc" do  

  describe file('~/.gemrc') do
    it { should be_file }
  end
end
```

And here is the error output:

```
       Check .gemrc
         File "~/.gemrc"
    should be file (FAILED - 1)       

Failures:       

  1) Check .gemrc File "~/.gemrc" should be file       
     Failure/Error: it { should be_file }       
       test -f \~/.gemrc       
       expected file? to return true, got false       
     # /tmp/busser/suites/serverspec/default/ruby_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'       

Finished in 0.06349 seconds       
1 example, 1 failure
```

Why doesn't the `file` resource see the .gemrc file as a normal file?

Comment: Does the file actually exist?

Comment: Yes, the file exists.

Comment: And it's readable by the user serverspec is running as? Can you show an `ls -al` of the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` shorthand is a path expansion supported by many popular shells, but it is not a true filesystem path. In effect, you are asking the file resource to look for a file `.gemrc` in an actual subdirectory named `~` (from an unspecified working directory, whatever it may be at the time the specs run).

I think you will need to specify an absolute path to the file (for example, `file('/home/username/.gemrc')`).